# JSP constant String too long

Tags: html, jsp

I've create a jsp page like this:

```
 <%  Object myName  = session.getAttribute("name"); 
     if(myName == null)
     {   String redirectURL = "http://www.google.com";  
         response.sendRedirect(redirectURL); 
     }
 %>
 <html>  ... some content ... </html>
```

**The content inside html tage is around 100k.** Now when I try to compile and run it in netbean/glassfish, i got an error message:

```
constant string too long
out.write("<html>.......</html>
```

I read it somewhere that there's a 64k limit. but i am not using "out.write" function at all, the jsp section is really small as you can see. How did this happen and how do I solve this?

What I want to achieve is first check if the session is valid, if not then redirect. if so, then show content. The content is quite large and static but i have no control over it :(. anyway i can achieve this?

Comment: That's a pretty big page; how can you possibly maintain it? That aside, a JSP page is compiled to a servlet--it doesn't matter that you don't *explicitly* call write; how do you think the output is produced? Take a look at the generated file.

Comment: As per your edit, this problem has nothing to do with whether to use redirect or not. To see it yourself, remove that whole `<% %>` block and you'll see that the problem still persists. My answer is also telling that the strange `redirect` logic has got nothing to do with this all (by the **"Unrelated"** statement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but i am not using "out.write" function at all*

JSP is internally using it. You know, JSP file is during "JSP compile" step converted to a Java class extending `HttpServlet` and everything ends up as Java code. Checkout the generated code in server's work folder to see it yourself.

Use runtime JSP includes using `<jsp:include>` to split out large fragments into separate JSP files.

E.g.

```
<body>
    <jsp:include src="/WEB-INF/header.jsp" />
    <jsp:include src="/WEB-INF/menu.jsp" />
    <p>Content</p>
    <jsp:include src="/WEB-INF/footer.jsp" />
</body>
```

Or, if that doesn't suit the concrete functional requirement, an alternative, provided that the HTML content is really *static* (i.e. it does not contain any JSP scriptlets, tags, expressions, etc), is to put the HTML content in its own `some.html` file and reference it by [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:import>`.

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
...
<body>
    <c:import url="some.html" />
</body>
```

This way it doesn't end up as part of JSP source code.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your redirect logic is missing a `return` statement. When executing the redirect, all the remaining JSP code is otherwise still invoked. Also, if you're repeating this [*scriptlet*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202) over all JSP files, you'd question if you can't better use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) for the job.

Comment: Thanks BalusC. a quick question: " it does not contain any JSP scriptlets, tags, expressions, etc" Can it contain javascript expression?

Comment: Uh, JavaScript is not part of Java/JSP. It's just part of HTML. You know, Java/JSP is a HTML code producer. HTML runs in webbrowser, not webserver. So does JavaScript. Also, the term "javascript expression" does not make any sense.