# error on my jsp page -- constant string too long

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to include a jsp page which contains huge content into a content area, I am getting this error :

> constant string too long , unable to compile class for jsp.

Any work around this problem ?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263158/jsp-constant-string-too-long

Comment: There is a limitation for string literals in java, if your string constant's length is more than 65535  then the class win not compile. see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323082/size-of-initialisation-string-in-java) and especially the link to the the [jvm specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7)

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution for your problem could be splitting this huge content into multiple jsp pages and including them dynamicly (using `<jsp:include>`) into one single jsp.